# man show pages in another languages only partially

Tags: centos, man, locale, language

I've faced a problem when trying to set French for a CentOS 8 system as my main language that some man pages are still in English.

For instance, `man man` is in French, but `man cp` or `man find` are in English.

`man -Lfr <command>` works in the same way. Any suggestions please ?

```
[student@localhost ~]$ locale
LANG=fr_FR.utf8
LC_CTYPE="fr_FR.utf8"
LC_NUMERIC="fr_FR.utf8"
LC_TIME="fr_FR.utf8"
LC_COLLATE="fr_FR.utf8"
LC_MONETARY="fr_FR.utf8"
LC_MESSAGES="fr_FR.utf8"
LC_PAPER="fr_FR.utf8"
LC_NAME="fr_FR.utf8"
LC_ADDRESS="fr_FR.utf8"
LC_TELEPHONE="fr_FR.utf8"
LC_MEASUREMENT="fr_FR.utf8"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="fr_FR.utf8"
LC_ALL=
```

```
[student@localhost ~]$ locale -a | grep fr
fr_BE
fr_BE@euro
fr_BE.utf8
fr_CA
fr_CA.utf8
fr_CH
fr_CH.utf8
fr_FR
fr_FR@euro
fr_FR.utf8
fr_LU
fr_LU@euro
fr_LU.utf8
```

Comment: You will have to install french versions of the man pages.

Comment: Could you point me on how can I do it please ?

Answer (score 1):

Some manpages, such as `cp`’s, don’t have a French translation available at all.

Up to version 7 included, RHEL and CentOS used to provide quite a few translated manpages, including `find`, in the `man-pages-fr` package, but that’s been dropped from version 8 because the manpages were largely outdated.

The [manpages-l10n project](https://manpages-l10n-team.pages.debian.net/manpages-l10n/) aims to improve this, but its manpages aren’t included in RHEL or CentOS (yet).

Comment: Thank you Stephen, but I can't find the package ```man-pages-fr```. Should I look for it in a specific repo ?
```[root@localhost ~]# dnf install man-pages-fr
Last metadata expiration check: 0:00:37 ago on Thu 06 Aug 2020 11:26:51 PM CEST.
No match for argument: man-pages-fr
Error: Unable to find a match: man-pages-fr```

Comment: Oops, sorry, it was present in version 7 and early builds of RHEL 8, but it was dropped (most of the manpages were oudated).

Comment: Compare https://tracker.debian.org/pkg/manpages-fr and https://tracker.debian.org/pkg/manpages-l10n .

Comment: @JdeBP I have no idea what you’re getting at; feel free to edit the answer (as always).